# Probabilistic test of matrix multiplication with one-sided error

Tags: algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms, matrices, linear-algebra

Given three matrices $A, B,C \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ we want to test whether $AB  \neq C$. Assume that the arithmetic operations $+$ and $-$ take constant time when applied to numbers from $\mathbb{Z}$.

How can I state an algorithm with one-sided error that runs in $O(n^2)$ time and prove its correctness?

I tried it now for several hours but I can't get it right. I think I have to use the fact that for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ at most half of the vectors $s \in S = \left\{1, 0\right\}^n$  satisfy $x \cdot s = 0$, where $x \cdot s$ denotes the scalar product$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_is_i$.

Comment: In the last paragraph: you need “for any _nonzero_ x,” which is obvious but crucial for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $AB=C$, then $A(Bx)=Cx$ for all vectors $x$. Generate vectors randomly and check. This known as [Freivalds' algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm). Wikipedia has details.

Comment: But i Need a One-sided Error algorith. Can someone help me?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't one-sided? (It is.)